# jQuery autocomplete - search by multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, autocomplete

**I would like to use jQuery Autocomplete plugin to create a user search function, and get informations from my MySQL database.**

I could search an user by his name, lastname, phone number or mail address, then show up all the matching users

The following script works, but something is messing.
If I'm searching for "BOUVIER Maxime" User, it works.
But, If I write "Maxime BOUVIER", it doesn't work anymore.

### Could someone please help me ?

This is my script:

```
$("#user").autocomplete({
            source: function (query, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "get_customer.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: query,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        response(data.map(function (value) {
                            return {
                                id: value.id,
                                value: value.nom,
                                email: value.email,
                                telephone: telephone
                            };  
                        }));
                    }    
                }); 
            },
            minLength: 2,
            delay: 200,
}});
```

here is my php script:

```
$keyword = $_POST['term'];
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();
$search_param= "%".$keyword."%";

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT id_client, nom, prenom, email,telephone  FROM client WHERE nom LIKE :search OR prenom LIKE :search OR  email LIKE :search OR telephone LIKE :search");
    $query->bindParam(":search", $search_param);            
    $query->execute();      


        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $a_json_row["id"] = $row["id_client"];
            $a_json_row["nom"] = strtoupperFr($row["nom"]). " ".ucwords($row["prenom"]);
            $a_json_row["email"] = $row["email"];
            $a_json_row["telephone"] = $row["telephone"];
            array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);

        }
    echo json_encode($a_json);
    $db = NULL;
```

*(I use PDO emulate ON, to use the same var for my query)*

Comment: Does your database have a Maxime BOUVIER? For all the database knows this guys doesn't exist even though the other way around it does. Try looking up for Full Text Search, that will probably solve your problem, unless you don't wanna go down the road of really long and complex sql queries

Comment: The users informations are stored in columns. So in first Name I have "Maxime", and in last name "BOUVIER". but I have nobody with exactly "Maxime BOUVIER", or 'BOUVIER Maxime'

Comment: Hmm still think a full text search would be the best solution but I see what you mean here. Try using something like ILIKE which is not case sensitive. Also another problem rises when you are searching for two words, which is once you write Maxime BOUVIER, the query will look for that exact match in nom, but I assume in nom you only store only one of the two words, hence it will return no results. BUT! I before you get to the second word, it should still return results for m, ma, max, maxi, maxim and maxime (if any of these actually exist)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the search to be made word by word, you need to split the words.
Replace this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id_client, nom, prenom, email,telephone  FROM client WHERE nom LIKE :search OR prenom LIKE :search OR  email LIKE :search OR telephone LIKE :search");
$query->bindParam(":search", $search_param);            
$query->execute();
```

With this:

```
    $where = "";
    $arrKeyword = explode(" ", $_POST['term']);
    if (!empty($arrKeyword)) {
        foreach ($arrKeyword as $i => $word) {
            $where .= " OR nom LIKE :search{$i} OR prenom LIKE :search{$i} OR  email LIKE :search{$i} OR telephone LIKE :search{$i} ";
        }
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id_client, nom, prenom, email,telephone  
            FROM client
            WHERE FALSE
            {$where} ";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    if (!empty($arrKeyword)) {
        foreach ($arrKeyword as $i => $word) {
            $search = "%$word%";
            $query->bindParam(":search{$i}", $search);
        }
    }

    $query->execute();
```